# Best way to send a numpy array in json?

Tags: python, json

I have a large numpy array (~ 200 MB) need to send to a socket in json format. The receiver (in java) knows the size of the array in advance. Will it work if I convert the numpy array into binaries using

```
A = np.ones((16800000, 3), dtype='float32')
data = A.tobytes()
```

Then I send the `data` as a value of a key?

```
{  "A": data }
```

Do I have to encode the numpy array using base64 or base32 before sending it in json format? As in my case, the speed is crucial, and encoding and decoding takes extra time and also extra space in this case.

Comment: Chunk it into smaller arrays, transmit them, put them together again. Messages of 200MB are going to go terribly slow. Bonus: turn the bytes of the ndarray into a b64 string to save space. In characters you'll be looking at 1G of data instead of 200MB

Comment: Sockets are perfectly able to transmit binary data - is there a real need to bloat it by 30% by base64-encoding it, or JSON-encoding it? Especially given that you say the receiver knows what it is...

Comment: Yes, it would also be fine to transmit the raw data directly, but json format is preferred. So I am wondering if it works to transmit binary data as a value in the json format without encoding.

Comment: Valid JSON only allows text, so if you have to use it, it may be worth compressing (e.g. with `lzma`) your data and converting it to base64 before sending.

Comment: I am presuming the sender and receiver are on different machines...

Comment: The sender and receiver are on the same machine.@MarkSetchell

Comment: Oh! Then you should almost certainly be looking at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell Does the multiprocessing library support memory sharing between python and java?

Comment: No, not as far as I know.

Comment: Consider clicking [edit] and adding into your question that the receiver is running Java.

Comment: It takes my relatively fast MacBookPro around 1.2s to base64 encode your array, and around 77ms to do `data = A.tobytes()`. So, if you want the data sent in less than 1.3s you don't have time for JSON, IMHO.

Comment: It takes my Mac around 78ms to put your array into a copy of **Redis** running on the local machine, with a Time-to-Live of 10s so it doesn't sit around filling RAM. You can also use **Redis** to notify the client that a frame of data has arrived. There are Java bindings for **Redis**. Also **bash** command-line bindings which allow you to inject data into your app easily for testing and also extract data for checking and monitoring.

Comment: @MarkSetchell What is the advantage of using Redis instead of the common TCP/IP socket solution in this case?

Comment: 1) The code is much easier to write 2) the sender and receiver are decoupled - you can send without the receiver running 3) you can inject test data, extract sample data and monitor the communication from outside using **bash**. Obviously YMMV. Also, if on the same machine, I wouldn't use TCP/IP sockets, but Unix-domain sockets, with address family AF_UNIX.